# Масштабирование ListView Android

Tags: gestures, android, listview, java

Имеется listView в который из интернета загружаются картинки, как реализовать возможность масштабировать listView с помощью мультитач жестов? 
Масштабировать(увеличивать/уменьшать) нужно сами картинки помещенные в пункты listView.

Comment: что значит масштабировать листВью?

Comment: никак, вот вроде был такой вопрос  http://hashcode.ru/questions/76061/java-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2